# Mophie juice pack is being drained too fast?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 8 installed. Sometimes, when I charge the iPhone with a mophie Juice Pack Case for iPhone 5, the power of the battery pack gets drained up in merely 5 seconds. This does not happen a lot, it happens randomly. I am sure my Juice Pack is fully charged.

What is the reason behind this? How can I fix this?

Comment: The power to what gets drained? The phone or the battery pack?

Comment: The battery pack. Sorry I did not mention it in the question.

Comment: Did you try with a different cable already?

Comment: What do you mean a different cable?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the SpacePack software and the battery does not drain quickly/too fast any longer.  However, I don't have access to the 32GB of storage now either.  Moreover, the latest SpacePack application only supports iPhone OS 8 or later [bummer].  Check your: Settings > Battery and notice the SpacePack application slaying your battery usage.